# DotNetNuke SQL 15350

Tags: sql, installation, dotnetnuke, integrated-security

Installing DotNetNuke 05.06.02 triggers a SQL error 15350 when using file(mdb) and Integrated Security. What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

There are threads about this problem at the DotNetNuke site.  [see here for instance](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Forums/tabid/795/forumid/107/threadid/231939/scope/posts/Default.aspx)

also this one has several threads [see](http://boardreader.com/thread/Installation_error_Number_15350_fhmmX4yyr.html)